# How to handle login/logout flow for multi users working on the same hardware computer

Tags: django, web-applications

We have a classic web application accessed from physical shop with their computer, using browser. We build user role (owner and staff) and credentials so far normal web application.

But we notice that lot of shop don't use it the way we expect. They create one owner account and everybody use the same account.

As main shops have only one computer and staff don't want to logout and type their login/password each time they take an order or need to search for information.
I know that POS system have code bar reader and staff can scan their QR code-barCode etc. before registering an order but for our web application we don't have this hardware. So I wonder if there's some best practice, library, example or idea on how to handle this case.

Comment: You could issue QR code by yourself and then utilize some QR reader libraries to read that and then perform the login for user

Comment: Thanks for the comment but in my question when I talked about code-bar I also include QR-code, for that I need some hardware to read. (Updated the question, added QRcode and Barcode)

Comment: You can utilize your customer phone's camera or webcam to scan the code. You can take a look at here https://github.com/dwa012/html5-qrcode, when you read QR data then just send it to your server to perform the login

Comment: Thanks for the comment but they use "computer" if they login with their smartphone it will not help to switch user on their computer or I don't understand correctly your suggestion.

Comment: yeah.. it's hard to integrate with their smartphone.. it will be easier if they have a webcam on their computer but some computer might not have that